# Save npm list to file

Tags: node.js, npm

I often move between computers when developing things. With npm and my `package.json` it means, or so I thought, everything would be the same when checked out. At least on the same major version `~4.0.0` or example.

However on my fast PC at work I get compile times of 11s compared to, at home, 1.2s.

I'd like to save out `npm list` to file so I can run a compare at home.

```
npm list --save npmlist.txt //for example
```

Comment: ... `npm list > npmlist.com` Shell 101.

Comment: bingo!, thats the one and now i know how to save files :)

Answer (score 22):

If you have problems with `npm shrinkwrap`, on windows you can use this:

```
npm list -json > npmlist.json
```

And for global packages

```
npm list -json -g > npmlist.json
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`npm shrinkwrap`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap) to generate a `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file. This file contains the exact versions of npm modules you have installed at that moment, recursively (so also modules of modules and so on). As long as that file sits in the root of your project, running `npm install` will install exactly those versions.

You can generate one on either pc to compare, or commit/copy the version generated on one pc to install the same versions of npm modules on the other.